# Symmetric matrices property

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, self-learning, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

Reading "M*athematical Physics: Classical Mechanics*" by A. Knauf, I found the following statement:

> The positive symmetric matrices with determinant 1 can be written as
>   $$
>     \begin{vmatrix}
>     A & B \\
>     B & C \\
>     \end{vmatrix}
> $$ with $A>0$, $B \in \mathbb R$, $C=\frac{1+B^2}{A}$.

I'm on self-teaching, so even if it's maybe a well-known property, I've never encountered it.

From what "process" stems this equality, and is it valid for any "positive symmetric matrix with determinant 1", or am I missing some context?

Comment: Write out the expression for the determinant and solve for $C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion), a real symmetric $2\times2$ matrix $M=\pmatrix{A&B\\ B&C}$ is positive definite if and only if $A>0$ and $\det M=AC-B^2>0$. So, if you want $\det M=1$, you need $C=\frac{1+B^2}A$.